# How do I get this UITableView to display?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can't figure out how to get this `UITableView` to display.

The code creates the table fully programmatically except for the nib.

The nib is a simple cell that works in other `UITableView`s in the same app.

When the table view is created and added as a subview to the `view`  and `reloadData` is called then `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` are both called. They both return `1`. (I checked in the debugger.)

However `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is never called.

I add the tableView to it's parent view with a NSLayoutConstraint that forces it's height, but nothing is displayed in that spot.

The view hierarchy debugger shows nothing in that spot and that there isn't a view on top of the table.

The app runs without any error or crashes.

I would appreciate your help.

```
@interface MyViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation MyViewCell
@end

@interface MyDataTableEntry : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@end

@implementation MyDataTableEntry
@end

@interface MyDataTable : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *rows;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINib* nib;
@end

@implementation MyDataTable

- (UINib*)getAndRegisterNib:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier {
    UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:reuseIdentifier bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    return nib;
}

- (id)initWithRows:(NSArray*) rows andView:(UIView*)view {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.rows = rows;
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.nib = [self getAndRegisterNib:@"PrototypeCell"];
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.rows.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyDataTableEntry* entry = self.rows[indexPath.row];

    [cell.button setTitle:entry.name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Here is a snippet that creates the table:

```
MyDataTableEntry* entry = [[MyDataTableEntry alloc] init];
entry.title = @"hello";
self.dataTable = [[MyDataTable alloc] initWithRows:@[entry] andView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.dataTable.tableView];
[self.dataTable.tableView setNeedsLayout];
[self.dataTable.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
[self.dataTable.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Where do you add the tableview to the superview? Please show that code

Comment: @john Cashew please assign array value   rows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", nil];   .than after you get the tableview.

Comment: @DarjiJigar were you able to get it to work?

Comment: You are registering your nib to the table view before actually allocating the table. Don't forget that sending a selector to nil won't throw an exception in objective c. Always check your objects for nil in cases like this and throw or log the result. This will make your life easier.

Comment: yes bro.add this line in viewdidload method

Comment: @puzzler Thanks for spotting that! However it's still not working.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've adding that code. Thanks for looking!

Comment: @john count the row array value in didload method. nslog(@"%ld",self.row.count);

Comment: @DarjiJigar I've confirmed it is `1`.

Comment: Where are you adding the tableview? i.e. Where is the snippet you have shown?  If it is in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` then the superview's frame will not be set correctly.  I strongly suggest you either use a storyboard/Nib or at the very least add four constraints to your tableview to set the top/bottom/leading/trailing to the superview. If you do this then remember to set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false on your tableview

Answer (score 3):

Without confirming in a debugger:

The problem is here:

```
self.dataTable = [[MyDataTable alloc] initWithRows:@[entry] andView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.dataTable];
```

`self.dataTable` is an NSObject. The second line should read something like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.dataTable.tableView];
```

I would also suggest that you engage in some refactoring. `MyDataTable` is not a view. It's a controller. So rename to `MyDataTableController`. Then the bug would have been more obvious.

I would also ask why you are doing this in code? you are already using nibs. So why not go to storyboards. Doing that and using `UITableViewController` as a base class should enable you to remove a lot of the code and potential bugs.

Comment: I apologize. When I hastily made that example code I introduced the error. The code in the app adds `self.dataTable.tableView` as a subview. This is in code so that it can be reused in multiple storyboards. Should I switch to using UITableViewController even if I stick to using code for this?

Comment: @JohnCashew I always use `UITableViewController` unless there is a design issue that stops me. For example, where the table view is only a part of the display that the controller is managing.  Another potential bug could be that when you create the table view based on the view's bounds, the bounds are actually size zero. Therefore the table is size zero. Breakpoint and check that.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. The problem is that frame is is size 0.

Comment: I changed the code to reset the table's frame and call setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded once the parent views' frame is not 0. Would you be able to offer any other advice? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is now that the width of the parent's frame is 0. The origin and height are both correct. I apologize if I'm being annoying.